# Compare and contrast the lightweight markup languages

Tags: documentation, markdown, markup, restructuredtext, textile

Please identify the most popular lightweight markup languages and compare their strengths and weaknesses.  These languages should be general-purpose markup for technical prose, such as for documentation (for example, Haml doesn't count).

See also: [Markdown versus ReStructuredText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276/markdown-versus-restructuredtext)

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/209897/text-formatter-tools/209902#209902

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I know of three main languages used commonly in the greater programming and tech community: Textile, Markdown, and reStructuredText.  All three can be learned in a couple of hours or "winged" with the cheat sheet nearby.

#### Textile

- Used by Redmine and the Ruby community
- 113 questions currently tagged on Stack Overflow
- The most similar to HTML, but least readable source
- Easiest nested lists of all three languages
- Not understandable to non-programmers or the HTML-ignorant
- Ideal for complex short documents (with links, nested lists, code, custom HTML); for example: short documentation, how-tos, blog or CMS content
- [Syntax reference](http://redcloth.org/hobix.com/textile/)

#### Markdown

- Doesn't seem to have a home language "community" but...
- 1274 questions tagged on Stack Overflow*
- Emphasizes source code readability, similar to email traditions
- Straightforward HTML embedding (you just type the tags out)
- No way to make tables besides embedding HTML
- You know it already if you know Stack Overflow
- Easy to learn if you already know reStructuredText
- Automatic email address obfuscation for the format <address@example.com> (with angle brackets)
- [Syntax reference](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)

#### reStructuredText (A.K.A. ReST)

- Popular in the Python community
- 285 questions tagged on Stack Overflow
- A bit persnickety about whitespace and alignment if you ask me
- Lists (especially nested lists) and paragraphs always seem to get in fights
- Readable by non-programmers
- Only format which can build a table of contents (via an extension in the Python reference implementation)
- Directly converts to other formats like PDF and XML
- Ideal for large documents with lots of prose (e.g. an alternative to docbook for a user manual)
- [Syntax reference](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html)

Comment: For users of ReST, http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ looks like a very nice tool for large tree-structured collections of reference documentation.

Comment: I don't have any problem with lists and paragraphs in reStructuredText when I hard-wrap things in Emacs. In fact, they function exactly like I would expect them to :-)

Comment: There are extensions to Markdown that allow composing tables in ASCII.

Comment: ReST has excellent tool support too: E.g. the browser based https://notex.ch is a good tool the experiment with, learn and use ReST (based on the sphinx.pocoo.org backend).

Answer (score 33):

You might also consider [asciidoc](https://asciidoc.org/):

- relatively readable markup
- support for a wide variety of document elements (e.g., bibliography,
  footnotes, . . .)
- some might perceive it as relatively 'picky' (vs. flexible) with respect to syntax

[asciidoctor](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoctor/latest/) supports output to:

- DocBook
- HTML
- man pages
- PDF
- EPUB

The [Awesome AsciiDoc](https://gitlab.eclipse.org/eclipse-wg/asciidoc-wg/asciidoc.org/-/blob/main/awesome-asciidoc.adoc) page provides a nice list of associated resources.

Comment: Unfortunately asciidoc has a horrible syntax for list items with multiple paragraphs: You have to separate them with a single line containing only a plus-sign (yes, a "+").

Comment: @Martin:  Are multi-paragraph list items really that important?  If you need more than one paragraph, wouldn't headings/sections be more appropriate than a list?

Comment: The biggest advantage of AsciiDoc is that it supports much more features. It can create books, have tip sections, many outputs... http://powerman.name/doc/asciidoc

Answer (score 21):

The Wikipedia page on [lightweight markup languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_markup_language) has a good comparison between the various options, as well as showing syntax for common uses (headings, bold, italics, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

I am attempting to cover all the various lightweight markup languages here:

http://www.subspacefield.org/~travis/static_blog_generators.html

As you can see, it started with "how can I make a secure blog" - i.e. one that generates static HTML, and I found myself ensnared in markup languages, templating systems, etc.

**Update**

I refocused only on LWMLs with python implementations, and theyre here:

http://www.subspacefield.org/~travis/python_lightweight_markup_languages.html

So far I've tried markdown and ReST, and I like the latter better for anything but
HTML snippets embedded in other pages.  Tables, cross refs, indirect links, etc...

Answer (score 4):

for documentation?
how about [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)?

I've use it for some of c/c++ project that I need to documentize.
Even you can 'abuse' it just like doxygen author uses for doxygen documentation